# ajax call to a method to update changes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to call a web method function in a webform through an ajax call which is updating values of textboxes in a division called "First" without refreshing the whole page but only those textboxes or division. My asp.net code containing the ajax with jQuery as follow:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="test_with_ajax.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="First" style="margin-left:45%">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
    <br />
  <div id="Second" style="margin-left:50%">
        <asp:Button ID="ShowButton" runat="server" Text="Show"/>
  </div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnableCdn="true" AjaxFrameworkMode="Disabled">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"/>
    </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <script>
        var pageurl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebForm1.aspx/Show()") %>';
        $('document').ready
        (
            function () {
                $("#ShowButton").click
                (
                    function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax
                        (
                          {
                              type: 'POST',
                              URL: pageurl,
                              async: "true",
                              success: function (x) {
                                  alert("Done Successfully with " + x.msg);
                              },
                              error: function (e) { alert("The call got failed due to " + e.msg); }
                          }
                        );
                        //$("#First").html("").append(data);
                    }
                );
            }
        )
    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my webform class contains the function am calling is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace test_with_ajax
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static void Show()
        {
             WebForm1 t = new WebForm1();
             t.TextBoxName.Text = "Sarthak";
             t.TextBoxID.Text = "66";
        }
    }
}
```

But am not getting the desired result I want. It shows the alert message of the success part of the ajax call but not updates the textboxes at all.

Comment: In success function check what value you get for 'x' using console.log(x);

Comment: Your webmethod is void, so they cannot return nothing, you should not update textbox in web method, but return the desired values in string form, then in the success handler of your ajax method update your controls client-side

Comment: did you check your web method is called correctly ?fix a break point and make sure its get fired. if it is fired then go with @InvernoMuto's comment i also think that is the better approach.

Comment: but how to return back to back values for all text boxes? actually in my actual program i am having like 10 text boxes. so? can u provide me a sample code?

Comment: @InvernoMuto can u provide me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not the right way of updating your textboxes because you are creating new object of webform and assiging values to textboxes. You should return data from webmethod and update textboxes in javascript code.Also add datatype in your ajax call.

Try like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Show()
{
 return "Hello world";
}
```

Than in you ajax success write like this

```
success: function (x) {
alert("Done Successfully with " + x.msg);
$('#TextBoxName').val(x.d);
},
```

This is only one string you can return array or list or obejct whatever you need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66562/discussion-on-answer-by-mairaj-ahmad-ajax-call-to-a-method-to-update-changes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, fix a breakpoint in code behind function , if it hits then change the type to string and return what ever you want then done your changes in client side

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="First" style="margin-left:45%">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
    <br />
  <div id="Second" style="margin-left:50%">
        <asp:Button ID="ShowButton" runat="server" Text="Show"/>
  </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> <!--add your jquery source path in src --> 


     <script type="text/javascript">
var sample="hai"


        $('document').ready
        (
            function () {
                $("#ShowButton").click
                (
                    function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "WebForm1.aspx/Show",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg)
                        {
                           //$("#TextBoxName").value(msg.d);
                        }
                    });
                     //$("#First").html("").append(data);
                    }
                );
            }

    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Show(string sample)
    {
       return sample;
    }
```

Comment: no still getting that error alert and in think that error is due to that line "dataType: "json"," on removing it it's again showing the success alert and also "#output" you using this as the target textbox i want to update the value of with the value returned by the function show?

Comment: Well just saw on net that adding scriptmanager is always preferable in such calls.

Comment: @Sarthak i think script manager is not necessary here check this discussion it will help you to understand use of that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169313/what-does-script-manager-control-actually-do

Comment: But i am using ajax call here for the page rendering only. I just want to let my division "First" refresh only not the whole page each time.

Comment: Ok, if i understand you right manner , then i think you want to do something with ajax without page refresh, i mean change the content or what ever you want with out page refresh ? am i right ?

Comment: Then check this simple method it will help you .http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: in your code you are try to achive  jQuery Ajax submit Form without page refresh using JSON

Comment: actually not json i am just trying to update text boxes on the basis of my database using ajax with jquery. This is my real question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315163/how-to-call-a-function-of-webform-through-jquery-with-ajax/27322892#27322892

Answer (score 0):

Type: "GET" - is required. DataType: "json" should be fine. Webmethod needs to return some serializable data in this case can return string. Inside Success function you can use Jquery and $("#TextBoxName").val('someval');

Best way to deal with these kind of error is to use Firefox and install Firebug. In Firebug use Script tab that is a place where you can see what is exactly happening and what data you getting from webMethod.

Comment: I tried what you said but it's still not working and am not getting how to use that firebug's script tag because there was not any mention of the method i called i.e. Show()

Answer (score 0):

```js
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function isDuplicate() As String
        Return "Hello text"
    End Function

End Class
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Default.aspx/isDuplicate',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Done Successfully with " + data.d);
                    $("#TextBox1").val(data.d);
                    $("#TextBox2").val(data.d);
                    $("#TextBox3").val(data.d);

                }
            }
                       );
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager  runat="server" ID="scr"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upd"></asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Click" OnClientClick="getData(); return false;" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since no post back is happening, the server side codes(in this case, the Show method) cannot render anything via Jquery Ajax.

Try to return a JSON data to client using the webmethod and use the same data to update the texboxes in the success call back function of $.ajax();

Try This:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace test_with_ajax
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static object Show()
        {
             object result = new 
        {
            TextboxName = "Sarthak";
            TextBoxID = "66";
        }
        return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And Your Ajax call should be:

```
<script>
    var pageurl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebForm1.aspx/Show()") %>';
    $('document').ready
    (
        function () {
            $("#ShowButton").click
            (
                function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax
                    (
                      {
                          type: 'POST',
                          URL: pageurl,
                          async: "true",
                          success: function (x) {
                              var data = JSON.parse(x.d);
                              $('#TextboxName').val(data.TextboxName);
                              $('#TextboxID').val(data.TextboxID);
                          },
                          error: function (e) { alert("The call got failed due to " + e.msg); }
                      }
                    );

                }
            );
        }
    )
</script>
```